# What type of data must be converted when passed between .NET and COM-based components?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, com

What is the correct answer to the following question:

What type of data must be converted when passed between .NET and COM-based components?

1. A class object containing only simple value types
2. COM-based Invariants
3. One-dimensional arrays
4. COM-based BSTR data
5. Simple value types

Comment: What do you mean by converted? marshalled?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're asking about blittable types. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx) on blittable types.

Lots of good info on interop marshaling in [this MSDN area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3.aspx).

1. For objects containing value types, you can implement the [IConvertible interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) where you define how each of the class members converts to a COM variant type. See more in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x07fbw8.aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforobjectsanchor3).
2. You can compare managed types to COM types [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sak564ww.aspx).
3. One-dimensional arrays of blittable types, such as an array of integers, are blittable. However, a type that contains a variable array of blittable types is not itself blittable.
4. System.String is marshaled to a BSTR by default, and vice versa.
5. Most simple types are blittable types that don't require conversion. See previous references.